# How to get the values from a list of dictionaries and append

Tags: python, dictionary

- I have lot of `employeeid`s - as is shown below.
- I need to get the value for business' name and append it to a list.
- I need to get the value policies and append to a list after checking `parent`.
- if parent is `Marketing` name has to added to level1.
- if parent is `Advertising` name has to added to level2.
- if some place Business is [] I need to pass `None` instead of Null List
- Also need to check key exists or not for some keys there is a chance of missing `policies`, `business`

```
    test = [{"id":"100","name":"A",
    "Business":[{"id":"7","name":"Enterprise"},
    {"id":"8","name":"Customer"}],
    "policies":[{"id":"332","name":"Second division","parent":"Marketing"},
    {"id":"3323","name":"First division","parent":"Marketing"}]},
    {"id":"101","name":"B",
    "Business":[{"id":"7","name":"Enterprise"},
    {"id":"8","name":"Customer"}],
    "policies":[{"id":"332","name":"Second division","parent":"Marketing"},
    {"id":"3323","name":"First division","parent":"Marketing"}]}]
```

My code

```
product = {}
product['id'] = {}
product['name'] = {}
product['Business'] = {}
x = [{**d, "Business": [i["name"] for i in d["Business"]]} for d in test]
product["policies"]["level1"] = []
product["policies"]["level2"] = []
for j in test["policies"]:
    if "Marketing" in j["parentName"]:
        d["level1"] += [j["name"]]
    if "Advertising" in j["parent"]:
        d["level2"] += [j["name"]]
```

Expecte out for 2 ids

```
[
  {
    "id": "100",
    "name": "A",
    "Business": ["Enterprise", "Customer"],
    "level1": ['Second division', 'First division'],
    "level2": [ ]
  },
  {
    "id": "101",
    "name": "B",
    "Business": ["Enterprise", "Customer"],
    "level1": ['Second division', 'First division'],
    "level2": [ ]
  }
]
```

Comment: dict you have posted has duplicate keys, consider re-formatting the code.

Comment: @Sushanth its list of dictionary not dictionary

Comment: There are two duplicate keys named `"id"` and `"name"`.(`"id":"100","name":"A"` was covered by `"id":"101","name":"A"`).

Comment: @Sushanth edited to B

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA edited to B

Comment: Your edit doesn't solve it, you could use `pprint.pprint` to see your result clearly.

Comment: You need to insert `}, {` before `"id":"101","name":"B",`

Comment: @Jasmijn edited thanks for the eye

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA  edited thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, fixed input (because in your example the `test` dict has duplicated keys)

```
test = [{"id": "100", "name": "A",
         "Business": [{"id": "7", "name": "Enterprise"},
                      {"id": "8", "name": "Customer"}],
         "policies": [{"id": "332", "name": "Second division", "parent": "Marketing"},
                      {"id": "3323", "name": "First division", "parent": "Marketing"}],
         },
        {"id": "101", "name": "B",
         "Business": [{"id": "7", "name": "Enterprise"},
                      {"id": "8", "name": "Customer"}],
         "policies": [{"id": "332", "name": "Second division", "parent": "Marketing"},
                      {"id": "3323", "name": "First division", "parent": "Marketing"}]}]
```

This code will do what you want

```
def do_the_thing(lst):
    resp = []

    parents_mapper = {
        'Marketing': 'level1',
        'Advertising': 'level2'
    }

    for el in lst:
        d = {
            'id': el['id'],
            'name': el['name'],
            'Business': [],
            'level1': [],
            'level2': []
        }
        for business in el.get('Business', []):
            business_name = business.get('name')
            if business_name:
                d['Business'].append(business_name)

        for policy in el.get('policies', []):
            policy_parent = policy.get('parent')
            parent_found = parents_mapper.get(policy_parent)
            policy_name = policy.get('name')
            if parent_found and policy_name:
                d[parent_found].append(policy_name)

        resp.append(d)
    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(4)
    pp.pprint(do_the_thing(test))
```

Comment: what will do if one id doesn't have business or any other key which is searching its throwing error key error, how to handle that

Comment: I adjusted my answer with additional `.get` so all those keys can be missing now.

Comment: How to pass if some place Business is [] I need to pass `None` to list

Answer (score 1):

**Updated to reflect edit**. I'm assuming missing keys mean you'd want to skip that particular dictionary.

```
def filter_policies(employee, parent):
    return [policy['name'] for policy in employee['policies'] if policy['parent'] == parent]

def process_employee(employee):
    return {'id': employee['id'], 'name': employee['name'],
        'Business': [business['name'] for business in employee['Business']],
        'level1': filter_policies(employee, 'Marketing'),
        'level2': filter_policies(employee, 'Advertising')}

output = []
for employee in test:
    try:
        item = process_employee(employee)
    except KeyError:
        pass # ignore employees with missing dictionary keys
    else:
        output.append(item)
```

Comment: what will do if one id doesn't have business or any other key which is searching its throwing error key error, how to handle that

Comment: You can use `try`/`except` to handle exceptions. If certain keys might be missing, please edit your question and specify the exact conditions, that way we know how best to deal with that.

Comment: Your code fails,i have changed key `Business` to `Occupation` or  any other key. expected out is still Business is there with [].

Comment: If you change the key in your input, you also need to change the key in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to win the prize for ugliest code here today, here is a solution using only comprehensions:

```
x = [{**d, "Business": [i["name"] for i in d["Business"]],
           "level1": [i["name"] for i in d["policies"] if i["parent"] == "Marketing"],
           "level2": [i["name"] for i in d["policies"] if i["parent"] == "Advertising"],
            } for d in test]

[d.pop("policies") for d in x]
pprint.pprint(x, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '100',
  'name': 'A',
  'Business': ['Enterprise', 'Customer'],
  'level1': ['Second division', 'First division'],
  'level2': []},
 {'id': '101',
  'name': 'B',
  'Business': ['Enterprise', 'Customer'],
  'level1': ['Second division', 'First division'],
  'level2': []}]
```

Comment: what will do if one id doesn't have business or any other key which is searching its throwing error key error, how to handle that

Comment: @aysh Then I would suggest changing the `for x in d["stufftocheck"]` into `for x in d.get("stufftocheck", [])`.